# How to read specific value from XElement object in C# (SqlDependencyEx)

Tags: c#, xml, sqldependencyex

I have to read specific item of XML-File ( well, not exactly FILE - this is XElement generated by SqlDependencyEx class, which sends me a record from DB which was just updated).

So I have something like this:

```
private void Send_Row_To_Queue(object sender, 
SqlDependencyEx.TableChangedEventArgs e)
{
XElement myElement = e.Data;
MessageBox.Show(myElement .ToString());
}
```

And in fact - it prints beautiful XML-formatted text...But I have no idea how could I read `<id>` in first node (inserted) out of it...

```
<root>
<inserted>
<row>
<id>13</id>
<line_number>12</line_number>
<comment>Wrongtypex</comment>
</row>
</inserted>
<deleted>
<row>
<id>13</id>
<line_number>12</line_number>
<comment>Wrongtypex</comment>
</row>
</deleted>
</root>
```

There are tons of answers where they explain how to read from PURE FILE (WHICH HAS IT'S PATH etc.) but none of them solved my specific problem.
Thanks for all help!

Comment: Have you tried `e.Data.Elements("inserted").First()`? Or are you after the value of the `id` element in the first `inserted` node?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow any example that use LINQ-to-XML to read an XML, with just a little modification. Here are 2 possible ways for example:

```
XElement myElement = e.Data;

// 1st way using method chaining
var id1 = myElement.Element("inserted").Element("row").Element("id").Value;

// 2nd way using XPath
using System.Xml.XPath;
var id2 = myElement.XPathSelectElement("inserted/row/id").Value;
```

**<kbd>[dotnetfiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aWKhAf)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank You very much! The first way works perfectly for me. I got a pure value now, thanks once again.